# Lua 4 outermost variable scope

Tags: lua, scope

Should I explicitly declare a variable in the outermost scope of a Lua 4 script a
local variable versus a global variable? Should I avoid one or the other? Thanks.

For instance:

```
local foo = 5
```

versus

```
faa = 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you already know that `local` variables are variables where they exist only within a certain scope, while normal variables are `global` and are included within the `_G` table. However, according to [Lua's Performance Guide](https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf), it also helps to make your code faster:

> Lua precompiler is able to store all local variables in registers. The result is that access to local variables is very fast in Lua. For instance, if `a` and `b` are local variables, a Lua statement like `a = a + b` generates one single instruction.

> So, it is easy to justify one of the most important rules to improve the performance of Lua programs: use locals!

Comment: Is this true for all scopes including the outermost one?

Comment: @posfan12 in the case of outermost scope, the main focus of using `local` is to improve the performance of the script, but in the case of internal scopes it has the functionality to exist only inside the scope